# How can I avoid TypeError: GroceryInventory.__str__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' here?

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to write a derived class, GroceryInventory, to represent the items' location, quantity in the store and a note to make new order using GroceryItem class I created earlier, which contains the items' description, price, size and unit.

My code returns

> TypeError: GroceryInventory.**str**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

with the test drive I wrote. Could someone tell me where I did wrong? And could someone be kindly enough to explain me a little about this specific error.

Here it is what I've written so far:

```
class GroceryItem:
    def __init__(self, description, price, size, unit):
        self.description = description
        self.price = price
        self.size = size
        self.unit = unit
        
    def calc_unit_price(self):
        return self.price/self.size
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.description}, {self.price}, {self.size}, {self.unit}'
    
    
class GroceryInventory(GroceryItem):
    def __init__ (self, description, price, size, unit, aisle, quantityout, quantityin):
        GroceryItem.__init__(self, description, price, size, unit)
        self.aisle = aisle
        self.quantityout = quantityout
        self.quantityin = quantityin
    
    def order_note(self, quantityout, quantityin):
        total = self.quantityout + self.quantityin
        if self.quantityout > total * 0.6:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Item: {self.description} - ${self.price:.2f} for {self.size} {self.unit} Aisle Number: {self.aisle} Number of item on shelves: {self.quantityout} Number of item in storage: {self.quantityin}'

# Test Drive:         
if __name__ == '__main__':
    carrots = GroceryInventory('carrots', 2.59, 1, 'pound', '12', '100', '600')
    donuts = GroceryInventory('glazed donuts', 4.95, 12, 'donuts', '12', '100', '600')
    olives = GroceryInventory('olives', 2.59, 6, 'ounces', '12', '100', '600')
    shopping_list = [carrots, donuts, olives]
    for item in shopping_list:
        print(GroceryInventory.__str__())
        print(f'\tUnit Price: ${item.calc_unit_price():.2f}')
```

I expected it to have three outputs: order note, description and the unit price. But I got a type error.

Comment: Probably you want to call this on the object and not the class. `print(GroceryInventory.__str__())` should become `print(str(item))`

Comment: You just need `print(item)`.  `str()` is implied by `print()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! My program is now running! You both helped a lot! @NickODell